# Change values of a vector to 0 and 1

Tags: r

From a vector I would like to make some values 0 and some values 1. It doesnt work, why?

```
  a <- c(1,34,5,3,6,67,3,2)


a[c(1,3,5)] <- 0 # works
a[!c(1,3,5)] <- 1 # doesnt work
```

Should look like

```
   a
    [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` is for logical values. Try `-`

```
a[-c(1,3,5)] <- 1
a
#[1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
> +!!replace(a,c(1,3,5),0)
[1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create the logical index with `%in%`

```
a[!seq_along(a) %in% c(1, 3, 5)] <- 1
a
#[1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```